# Spark SQL : INSERT Statement with JDBC does not support default value

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-jdbc

I am trying to read/write data from other databases using JDBC.
just following the doc https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html

But I found Spark SQL does not work well with Default value or AUTO_INCREMENT

```
CREATE TEMPORARY VIEW jdbcTable
USING org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc
OPTIONS (
  url "jdbc:postgresql:dbserver",
  dbtable "schema.tablename",
  user 'username',
  password 'password'
)

INSERT INTO TABLE jdbcTable (id) values (1)
```

Here is my DDL

```
CREATE TABLE `tablename`  (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `age` int(11) NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE
)
```

The error `org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: unknown requires that the data to be inserted have the same number of columns as the target table: target table has 2 column(s) but the inserted data has 1 column(s), including 0 partition column(s) having constant value(s).`

Is there any way to support Default value or AUTO_INCREMENT? thx

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered this same issue with columns with `DEFAULT` and also `COMPUTED` columns. If you are using SQL Server you can consider an `AFTER INSERT TRIGGER` otherwise you may need to calculate the id on the `INSERT` side.